# Novel about an alien spacecraft in the asteroid belt which knocks rocks out of the way by hitting them with its tail

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space

A bizarre novel I read some time in the 1970s.

The only thing I remember is that they find a clear space in the asteroid belt (this is one of those books back when many people though the asteroid belt was crowded, with rocks jostling constantly). The spacecraft is long and thin and it keeps a space clear by 'batting' rocks out of the way with its tail.

It's not *Raiders from the Rings* (1962) by Alan E Nourse.
Posted on AbeBooks & BookSleuth about 2007, but no suggestions.

Comment: _"they find a clear space in the asteroid belt"_ - Does the _"they"_ in this sentence refer to the aliens? Also, can you say anything more about the aliens? Were they invaders or explorers? And were they the main characters, or was the story told from a human perspective?

Comment: Sorry. Humans find the alien ship. I don't remember the details but it may have been something along the lines of "the strange stories/ideas/instructions seem to originate from co-ordinates XXX for many years/decades/centuries, let's go and look there". I think the alien ship turns up only at the end of the story. Don't recall if the aliens were alive or not.